# Exclude result from query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a that takes the tags of a current video and matches them with other videos for results. The only issue is I would like to exclude the video that the tags are from (exclude a specific vid_id). I tried the following but the line `AND vid_id!=some_id` breaks it. Any ideas?

```
$sql = "SELECT video.*,COUNT(*) as count FROM tags LEFT JOIN video 
ON (tags.vid_id = video.vid_id) 
WHERE name IN(?,?) AND vid_id!=some_id 
GROUP BY vid_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Try the query in an SQL client - it'll reply with the errors (like "missing )" or "vid_id column name is ambiguous".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Did you forget to **close the parenthesis** after the ON clause?
2. Also, since your vid_id column is present both in the video table
   and in the tags table, you'll need to **specify the tablename in the
   WHERE-clause** (yes, even though the ON-statement requires they be
   equal)

That gives:

```
$sql = "SELECT video.*,COUNT(*) as count 
FROM tags 
LEFT JOIN video 
ON (tags.vid_id = video.vid_id)
WHERE name IN(?,?) 
AND video.vid_id != some_id 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: What's the difference between `!=` and `<>` in MySQL? I always thought you had to use `<>`, but [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) implies they're the same thing.

Comment: Oh sorry, those are exactly the same. Changed the query to closer ressemble the original query - less chance of confusion about `!=` or `<>` being the culprit here.

Comment: I thought so. I didn't notice the closing paren until you added the explanation to the beginning of your post. The only thing that stuck out to me was the `<>` change, so I thought that was your fix.

Comment: Sorry - I learned that on StackOverflow... first I took my time to write up an entire answer, only to find someone faster posted 2 lines and got enough upvotes already... now I solve, then I explain :)

Comment: hahaha. Nice method Konerak. I however take greater consideration over the people that take the time to respond and help me first. Thanks for your time and the great answer.

Comment: Oh it feels a bit dirty at first, but it's just a different kind of competition really. You're forced to consider what's most important and write briefly and clearly. Only then can you elaborate, explain and document with links. As long as you don't start your first answer with "Do a `DELETE FROM table` to solve that" to then change that to "Do a `DELETE FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` to solve that", you're fine ;)